# Opening popup without a server request

Tags: javascript, modalpopupextender

We are trying to develop a timeout feature in application where we want alert user saying that the application log out will happen in x time will display the count down timer. Once the timeout we will be force fully logging out the user. For displaying the log out information we thought of displaying a pop-up with relevant message which can close itself and initiate log out on timeout. The problem with display of pop-up is we have to send a request to the server which will reset the session timeout set at server level.

For achieving the above requirement is there any way to open a pop-up without sending the request to server. We will decide the content of the pop-up using DHTML.

Comment: Note: We don't want to use any kindly of local creation of html file and rendering it. We are using JSPs and servlets in out application.

Comment: You might wanna have a look at "modals", as they are fake pop-ups in the same window, and a lot easier to handle. And also, they won't be stopped by pop-up blockers.

Comment: Thanks a lot for all your input, we will try them out and will update the results :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree with Guillaume that a DHTML window would be better, but this should work if you want a real popup window.

```
var win = window.open('about:blank');
win.document.body.innerHTML = '[Window body content here]';
```

Comment: It was a simple but effective solution :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use jQuery both to display an alert with a count down and to send an ajax request to the server resetting the session timeout, without having to refresh the screen.

Kind regards,
Guillaume Hanique

Answer (score 1):

Best bet (simple, poerful, documented):
http://digitarald.de/project/roar/

Relies on [Mootools](http://mootools.net).

Comment: It was not possible to implement this solution in our product but thanks for suggesting it. We will implement it in our new products :)